# Замена CSS свойства gap для Safari?

Tags: css, flexbox, safari, media-queries

Сверстал календарь на флексах и гапах. Захожу тестить на сафари, а там гапы просто не работают. Искал в интернете, но не нашел ответа на свой вопрос. Итак, **чем заменить gap**?
Пробовал

```
gap: 1px;  
-moz-column-gap: 1px; 
-webkit-column-gap: 1px;
```

Но не помогает.

Comment: сафари не поддерживает `gap` у `flex`. Либо делайте `margin` или как вариант можно на гридах

Comment: Да, сделал через margin. На гридах тоже пробовал, но с ним куча проблем.

Comment: только учтите что margin у крайних элементов надо будет убрать с помощью `:nth-child()`